# Unity 4.6, set up iPhone 5 sized portrait pixel perfect canvas

Tags: iphone, unity-game-engine

How do you set up the canvas in Unity to be the exact size of an iPhone 5, portrait? It's supposed to be 640x1136 pixels,  but I don't get the canvas to be exact. Using Unity 4.6 RC 3.

[image]